# Pass Object as Prop - Reusable Dropdown component

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a reusable Dropdown component and I want to map through an object that I'm passing down to the component like this:

```
const dropdownitems = [
  { name: 'Menu Item 1', action: '/menuitem1' },
  { name: 'Menu Item 2', action: '/menuitem1' }
]

// Reusable component
<Options getdata="dropdownitems" icon="notifications" />
```

I struggle to figure our how should I pass on this as prop in the .map:

```
...
{props.getdata.map(({name, action}) => (
  <TextLink href={action} text={name} />
))}
...
```

This is of course returning: 
**Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**

Edit: Corrected the object(my bad). This is how I actually have it in code.

Hope this makes sense.
Thanks for having a look!

Comment: Ok well 2 problems, first you're passing down this as a prop: `getdata="dropdownitems` but that's not your array, it's literally a string with the value  "dropdownitems". If you want to pass a variable, you need curly braces: getdata={getdata}. Secondly, you'll get that error if `getdata` is not defined, which can happen if you forget to pass it down, or if the array is fetched asynchronously or the likes. So you should check that it's there before you map it, e.g. `{props.getdata && props.getdata.map(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with how you are passing it as a prop. The way you are passing it interprets it as string. To pass an array , enclose it within a flower braces. Also icon is passed as string, just have a look at it unless you absolutely want it as string. Use something like this:

```
const dropdownitems = [
  { name: 'Menu Item 1', action: '/menuitem1' },
  { name: 'Menu Item 2', action: '/menuitem1' }
]

// Reusable component
<Options getdata={dropdownitems} icon="notifications" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const notifications = []; /* some kind of data */
const items = [
  { name: 'Menu Item 1', action: '/menuitem1' },
  { name: 'Menu Item 2', action: '/menuitem1' }
]

// Reusable component
<Options getdata={items} icon={notifications} />
```

---

also "getdata" is a non-descriptive name; i suggest use "data" or "items" or "options" ...

and with renames:

```
<Options options={items} icon={notifications} />
```

in child component:

```
...

{props.options.map((el) =>{ /* code here */})}
...
```

Comment: @DorinV did you rename everything accordingly?

Comment: yes, the issues was that I was passing down the object as string: "items" rather than as an object: {items} - Beginners' mistakes .. :) Thanks!